# Embeding SwingNode in javafx 11

Tags: java, javafx

Im using Gradle (no modular) to use javafx 11, and i have problems when i try to embed a jpanel inside the swing node.
(i export the module java.swing inside the build.gradle because swing node wasnt inside the traditional javafx modules.)

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swingNode.setContent(new JButton("jelo"));

        }
    });

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.overrideNativeWindowHandle(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljdk/swing/interop/LightweightFrameWrapper;JLjava/lang/Runnable;)V
at javafx.swing/com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.overrideNativeWindowHandle(Native Method)
at javafx.swing/com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.overrideNativeWindowHandle(SwingNodeInteropN.java:129)
at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.notifyNativeHandle(SwingNode.java:328)
at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.addSceneListeners(SwingNode.java:606)
at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.doCreatePeer(SwingNode.java:644)
at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.access$100(SwingNode.java:120)
at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode$2.doCreatePeer(SwingNode.java:146)
at javafx.swing/com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.SwingNodeHelper.createPeerImpl(SwingNodeHelper.java:65)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.createPeer(NodeHelper.java:94)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getPeer(Node.java:2589)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.doUpdatePeer(Node.java:785)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.access$200(Node.java:398)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$1.doUpdatePeer(Node.java:429)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.updatePeerImpl(NodeHelper.java:162)
at javafx.swing/com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.SwingNodeHelper.updatePeerImpl(SwingNodeHelper.java:70)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.updatePeer(NodeHelper.java:102)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.syncPeer(Node.java:710)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2366)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2512)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:412)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:411)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:438)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:519)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:499)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:492)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:320)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2365)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2512)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:412)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:411)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:438)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:519)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:499)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:492)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:320)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.overrideNativeWindowHandle(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljdk/swing/interop/LightweightFrameWrapper;JLjava/lang/Runnable;)V
at javafx.swing/com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.overrideNativeWindowHandle(Native Method)
at javafx.swing/com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.overrideNativeWindowHandle(SwingNodeInteropN.java:129)
at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.notifyNativeHandle(SwingNode.java:328)
at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.setContentImpl(SwingNode.java:394)
at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.lambda$setContent$5(SwingNode.java:347)
at javafx.swing/com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.SwingNodeHelper.runOnEDT(SwingNodeHelper.java:170)
at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.setContent(SwingNode.java:347)
at uni.cmmsb.baseGUI$1.run(baseGUI.java:83)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I added the swing node by code because i cant add it by sceneBuilder 11, idk why i cant do it.

gradle build:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile files('src/main/libs/kabeja-0.4.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/kabeja-svg-0.4.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/javafx-swing-11-linux.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/fxyz3d-0.5.1.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/fxyz3d-client-0.5.1.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/fxyz3d-importers-0.5.1.jar')
}


javafx {
    version = "11.0.2"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml','javafx.swing']
}

mainClassName = 'uni.cmmsb.MainYui'
```

Comment: Have you added `javafx.swing` to your build? Edit your question and post your build.gradle file.

Comment: just done! , i use javafx.swing to get the SwingNode

Comment: +1 on using FXyz3D! But you can retrieve from Maven Central. Probably the same for kabeja. As for the `javafx-swing-11-linux.jar`, it shouldn't be there. Remove it and try again.

Comment: i added javafx-swing-11-linux.jar recently because i was trying tha's not the problem :c, the kabeja 
It is a modification of the original, I only have that jar, 
and when I try to get the fxyz from maven I get an error, which does not find one of the packages, so I decided to use the .jar

Comment: (FXyz3D issue, unrelated to this question, add `maven { url = "http://maven.jzy3d.org/releases" }` to your repositories and try again?)

Comment: Ok, a lot of thanks to you for the fxyz fix, but now, how can i solve the swing problem?

Comment: The `SwingNode` works for me (on Mac). Make sure you don't have that local javafx jar. Clean the project and run again.

Comment: Same issue here with maven